# how to display images from database in php?

Tags: php

i write bellow code to display images from database

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("test");
$qry = "select id from image";
$res = mysql_query($qry) or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
{
  echo "<img src=image.php?id='$row[0]'>";
}
?>
```

Image.php

```
<?php
$query = mysql_query("SELECT img FROM images WHERE id = ".$_GET['id']);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
if($type=="pjpeg")
$type="jpeg";
header("Content-type:$type");
echo $row['img'];
?>
```

but this will not work. it display blank image icon.

Comment: If you analyze your http-traffic what content-type does the header say that your image is?

Comment: i dont know that how to know ?

Comment: Do you have a chrome browser or firefox with firebug plugin? Then it is easy to check it in the "Network"-tab. Look at the request that goes to image.php?id= and you should see what the server returns. Also make sure that you don't return any white space before or after the image

Comment: i checked as u said.. i got this string der

<img src=image.php?id='2'><img src=image.php?id='1'><img src=image.php?id='3'>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You also might [use base64 encoding](http://webcodertools.com/imagetobase64converter/Create) to build in the image. Like

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAWgBaAAD/4gxYSUNDX1BST0ZJTEUAAQEAAAxITGlubwIQAAB..." />
```

**UPDATE, base64 encoding example**

You can do that easily:

```
<?php
$imageId = intval($_GET["id"]);

$query = mysql_query("SELECT img FROM images WHERE id = ". $imageId);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($query);

$mime = null;
// place $type init. here
if ($type=="pjpeg") // <<< where do you get $type btw?
    $mime = "image/jpeg";

$b64Src = "data:".$mime.";base64," . base64_encode($row["img"]);
echo '<img src="'.$b64Src.'" alt="" />';
?>
```

Comment: but how to use this base64 encoding in my coding?

Comment: @jay updated my answer. Also pay attention that you have uninitianlized variable which will be empty in content type

Comment: thanks, i changed my image.php by this code, but still i getting empty image icon :(

Comment: @jay You should not change image.php to the base64 example code. This b64 code outputs `<img>` tag already. Take a look at your example. This construction `if($type=="pjpeg")` will cause E_NOTICE, and script will send header `Content-type:`. You need to initilize variable `$type`.

Comment: @jay First of all try to replace that code `if($type=="pjpeg")
$type="jpeg";
header("Content-type:$type");` to `header("Content-type: image/jpeg");` and see what happens.

Comment: ya already changed that in image.php but still i didnt got images

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20236/discussion-between-nkamm-and-jay)

Comment: Link to "use base64 encoding" in answer is dead.

Answer (score 1):

`jpeg` is not a valid Content-Type, it should be `image/jpeg`

Comment: i tried this also, but images are not display.. only blank image icon i got.

Answer (score 0):

As above 
+ be sure to pass the `replace = true` parameter to the header function.

`header( 'Content-Type: image/jpeg', true );`

Comment: i placed true parameter inside header function, but still i didn't got images.. only blank icons appear

Comment: and what do you see when open the actual image URLs in your browser directly?

Comment: <img src=image.php?id='2'> this is image url i got by inspect element

Comment: can you write a simple code which can retrieve more than one images from database?

Comment: the single quotes around the id number look like a potential mistake.

Comment: So open up the URL and what do you get?

Comment: i removed that simple code now i got this string <img src="image.php?id=1">

Comment: so open up the URL in your browser. What do you get?

Comment: i opened this url like image.php?id=1 , there also i got one blank image icon

Comment: you're going to have to debug this properly. Try viewing the image URL  output from the command line showing the headers, like: `$ curl -i http://localhost/whatever/image.php?id=1`

Comment: If the output is blank, chances are you've got php errors that aren't showing up. enable `display_errors` and/or `log_errors` and check the error logs.