# Error diplaying image in php

Tags: php, image, upload, photo

I have an error displaying images in php, my script used to work, and now it doesnt :(.

My Script is this:

```
$image_id = intval($_REQUEST['id']);    

//Query database for our images data and grab it fromt the array returned
$result = mysql_query(sprintf("SELECT data, file_size, mime_type FROM _system_image WHERE id = %d;", $image_id));
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
//Set the headers so the browser knows an image is coming and then echo out the data
header("Content-type: " . $row['mime_type']);
header("Content-length: " . $row['file_size']);
echo $row['data'];  
exit();
```

And my script for uploading photos is:

```
            //Create an array of potential errors for uploading images
            $image_uploading_errors = array(1 => 'Maximum file size in php.ini exceeded',
                                            2 => 'Maximum file size in HTML form exceeded',
                                            3 => 'Only part of the file was uploaded',
                                            4 => 'No file was selected to upload.');
//Get the filename and size (validation of size is done in html part!)
            $filename = $_FILES[SINGLE_IMAGE_UPLOAD_NAME]['name'];
            $img_size = $_FILES[SINGLE_IMAGE_UPLOAD_NAME]['size'];
            //Use the tmp name, to 'getimagesize' which returns an array of info (not just images size!) and also to get the  data from the image
            $info = getimagesize($_FILES[SINGLE_IMAGE_UPLOAD_NAME]['tmp_name']);
            $data = file_get_contents($_FILES[SINGLE_IMAGE_UPLOAD_NAME]['tmp_name']);
            //Get the mime type from the img_size (an array of info)
            $mime_type = $info['mime'];


            //Put all the info into a new image object
            //(img_id, album_id, album_pos, name, low_res_mime, low_res_size, high_res_mime, high_res_size, available_sizes, date_uploaded, date taken, caption)
            $img = new Image(NULL, NULL, NULL, $filename, NULL, NULL, $mime_type, $file_size, NULL, new DateTime(), NULL, NULL);
            $img->set_high_res_data($data);

            //Return the image!
            return $img;
```

The Image class used is something that I've written myself, and all the variables like $mime_type do go correctly into the database.

I feel like this may be a repeat question, but I have looked on here, and none of the solutions (that I found) were useful!

EDIT:

The error is "The image '...' cannot be displayed because it contains errors." Where '...' is the file name.

I usually try to display the image with the html:  wher %d is an integer.

The problem is that the image doesnt get siaplyed at all.

SINGLE_IMAGE_UPLOAD_NAME is a constant for the array key in $_FILES.

EDIT:

Not really a solution, but I changed to use the method to display images in this question and now it works:

[how to display images from database in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13602259/how-to-display-images-from-database-in-php)

Comment: What's the error? Where does the error come from? What do you want from us?

Comment: The error is "The image '...' cannot be displayed because it contains errors." Where '...' is the file name. It comes from when I try to access the script directly, its usually accessed like this <img src="scripts/system_image_data.php?id=%d" /> but that doesnt give any werrors, it just doesnt display it. I was hoping that someone would have an why the image wouldnt display at all. Sorry Im tired at the moment, so I should have said all that already. Any suggestions for how I should phrase the question, I couldnt think of what to put?

Comment: @Madbreaks I also don't get your problem with it not being a question (I admit its not particularly descriptive, but it is still accurate) as others post 'non questions' all the time and especially when you've posted a something that 'is not a question' previously yourself!

Comment: This is a Q&A site.  If you're unsure of how to properly ask questions here, please read the FAQ: http://stackoverflow.com/faq