# Displaying an image from a database

Tags: php

I have looked at most of the threads re this topic but I am still in the dark! I understand that storing an image in a database is not best practice but that's what I have. I have managed to upload the images no problem but when I try to display them I get this message.

The image ***** cannot be displayed because it contains errors.

I have tested the code to see if the file is actually been selected by echoing the file content and I get the pages of code relating to the image but when I try to display the image using the header (Content-type:image/jpeg) I get the above message. I am storing the image as a longblob. This is my code

```
<?php
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$host = "localhost";
$database = "test";

mysql_connect($host, $username, $password)
    or die("Can not connect to database:   ".mysql_error());

mysql_select_db($database) or die("Can not select the database: ".mysql_error());

$id = 3;

if (!isset($id) || empty($id) || !is_int($id)) {
    die("Please select your image!");
} else {
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT image FROM images WHERE image_id='".$id."'")
        or die(mysql_error());
    //echo $query;
    $row = mysql_fetch_row($query);
    $content = $row['image'];

    header('Content-type: image/jpg');
    echo $content;
}
```

Any help much appreciated
Thanks#
Sarita

Comment: Please have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13602259/how-to-display-images-from-database-in-php

Comment: are u sure that u r image is uploaded into the database?           to insert images that are bigger than 1MB you have to increase the max_allowed_packed option in the server configuration file. You can change that in the Startup Variables section in the MySQL Administrator on the Networking page. Please check this http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?20,17671,27914

Answer (score 1):

1. `<?php` is missing. This leads to your code not being interpreted as PHP, but send to the client unprocessed.
2. Remove `?>`. It can lead to extra output that you did not intended. Extra output that you did not intended might be acceptable in text file, but can trip the parser of binary files.
3. Open an image that *cannot be displayed because it contains errors*  with a text editor to see additional errors.

Comment: If I remove the php tags (both are there but I didn't copy the end tag to the question) it is parsed as am HTML and I'm not sure what errors I should be looking for.

Comment: Went with uploading the images to a separate folder and storing the file path on the database - much simpler than the other way and the user doesn't know the difference. Thanks everyone for your help

Answer (score 0):

The mime type should be `image/jpeg` not `image/jpg`.

Make sure there is nothing before `<?php` and nothing after `?>` at the end, including the unicode BOM (which some editors might not display).

If gpc_magic_quotes is on, you might have stored the image in the database with additional backslashes in it. Make sure the images in the database are formatted correctly.

Comment: Changed to image/jpeg, checked there is nothing before or after the php tags and turned gpc_magic_quotes on but still no luck.