# PHP - images stored as BLOB displayed as broken links

Tags: php, mysql, image, blob

I'm working on a store application in PHP and am having trouble displaying stored on MySQL database. I'm storing the images as medium `BLOB` type and I'm confident that the images are properly formatted during and after being uploaded to the database. (I can download the images from the database directly and view them as jpeg images).

But if I try to display my images in the web page, I am getting the broken image icon. The only way I've been able to get the picture to display from sql is by using base64 encoding, but that's not the method I want to use.

Here is my code. It fetches all the products from the database and displays their id, description, and image in a table row.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<title>Image Test</title>
<body>
<?php
    include("mylibrary/login.php");
    login();
    $query = "SELECT prodid, description FROM products";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

    echo "<table width=\"50%\" cellpadding=\"1\" border=\"1\">\n";
    echo "<tr><td>Product ID</td><td>Description</td><td>Image</td></tr>\n";
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
    {
        $prodid = $row['prodid'];
        $description = $row['description'];

        echo "<tr><td>$prodid</td><td>$description</td>\n";  
        echo "<td><img src=\"showimage.php?id=$prodid\" width=\"80\" height=\"60\"></td></tr>\n";
    }
    echo "</table>\n";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the `showimage.php` code. The `showimage.php` file is only showing a broken image. I've looked at the raw data of the images and they're all formatted correctly. :

```
<?php
//header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
   $prodid = $_GET['id'];
   $con = mysql_connect("localhost", "test", "test") or die('');
   mysql_select_db("store", $con);

   $query = "SELECT picture from products WHERE prodid=$prodid";
   $result = mysql_query($query);
   $row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);
   $picture = $row['picture'];

   header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
   echo $picture;
?>
```

I'd really appreciate help in understanding why this code isn't working. I've read numerous articles on this site and from google searches and they all say that this code should work.

As a side note, I don't want to use the base64 encoding method because I'm taking a class and this is the method that we're using (I'm also the only person who is having this problem).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13602259/how-to-display-images-from-database-in-php

Comment: i tried the script which is there as answer with different image types it is working fine, please give it a look,

Comment: @mkaatman Thanks for responding, but that doesn't answer my question. I don't wan't to use base64. I'm interested in knowing why my current setup is not working since I've seen other people have no problems using it without having to use base64.

Comment: It might help if you explained why you don't want to use base64? What problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, the code looks almost okay. The problem with pictures is, it has to be exactly correct, otherwise it cannot be correctly displayed. Try the following things:

- Use "Content-Type: image/jpeg instead of "Content-type: image/jpeg"
- Remove the closing tags ?> in showimage.php - if there is a space after the closing tags, that could be your problem. You should never use closing tags for PHP-only files.

If that does not help, remove the header for the content type and have a look at what is actually returned to you by calling the picture url and compare the data to the original image. That way you can confirm that the picture data is correct or what the differences are.