# Prevent Images from direct access

Tags: php, html, image

Is there any way I can setup a gallery that is accessible just to the members?
I can setup the php login and all.
But i want the images to be handled securely. Anyone having the image URL should not be able to access the image until not logged in as a member.

Comment: you will need to view your images in php scripts, some thing like this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/13602453/2359679

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to display images from database in php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13602259/how-to-display-images-from-database-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

You can use things like:

Have the images in a location which is not accessible to the public.

Use code for images like:

```
<img src="/imageproxy.php?image=<?=$imagename?>" />
```

And an **imageproxy.php** file:

```
$image = filter_input(INPUT_GET,"image");

$imageWithPath = "/path/to/images/".$image
if (/* is authenticated */ && is_readable($imageWithPath) && /* user can access $image*/) {
    header("Content-Type: ".mime_content_type($imageWithPath));
    $handle = fopen($imageWithPath,"r");
    fpassthru($handle);
    fclose($handle);
    exit; 
} else {
   http_response_code(403);
   exit;  
}
```

This is an alternative to using base64 images since this way you can load images asynchronously instead of pre-loading them.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent images from direct access you can set sessions and display things if session is set

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['username']) && !empty($_SESSION['username']))
        {
             echo "<img src='imgname.png' />";
        }
?>
```